# How to get the raw response and URL from HttpResponseDecorator

Tags: groovy, httpresponse, httpbuilder

The [REST Client](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html) of [HTTP Builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/) returns a [HttpResponseDecorator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/class-use/HttpResponseException.html). How can I get the raw response out of it (for logging purposes)?

EDIT (some code might be handy):

```
    withRest(uri: domainName) {
        def response = post(path: 'wsPath', query: [q:'test'])
        if (!response.success) {
            log.error "API call failed. HTTP status: $response.status"
            // I want to log raw response and URL constructed here
        }
```

Answer (score 18):

I've been having a nightmare with the same problem. Here's my solution using HTTPBuilder:-

```
response.failure = {resp ->
    println "request failed with status ${resp.status}, response body was [${resp.entity.content.text}]"
    return null
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: When I did the above, I got "java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream."

Comment: I had the same issue. It was caused because I was inadvertently reading the content twice. The first was through my IDE's debugger. Content is not repeatable ([HttpClient doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29)) and therefore can't be read more than once. By removing the 'watch' in the debugger, it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I used XmlUtil, it returns the pretty printed xml:

```
    def data = respXml.data
    assert data instanceof groovy.util.slurpersupport.GPathResult

    println "${XmlUtil.serialize(data)}"
```

If your data is a parsed response from groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`println response.data`

Comment: http://javadox.com/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.6/groovyx/net/http/HttpResponseDecorator.html#getData() That's literally the exact opposite of the raw response.